# is it possible to map all requests to a route under a certain path i.e '/api/**' to a different app in pcf?

Tags: routes, cloud-foundry

As the title suggests, I have a frontend app and a backend api. Each with their own manifest running in pcf in their own containers. They are on the same origin. I want to route all api requests to the backend api, and every other request to the frontend app. This is currently possible via map-route cmd in pcf cli or app manager. For every endpoint I have in my backend api, I map the endpoint to a route 'api/path1', 'api/path2', 'api/path3', 'api/path4', 'api/path5', api/path6', 'api/path7', 'api/path8', 'api/path9'................ except the only problem is I have to list every single endpoint I want mapped. Wildcards are not supported..at least I haven't been able to get them to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For every endpoint I have in my backend api, I map the endpoint to a route 'api/path1', 'api/path2', 'api/path3', 'api/path4', 'api/path5', api/path6', 'api/path7', 'api/path8', 'api/path9'

If everything under `/api/` goes to your backend app, then it's not necessary to map individual paths like this. It should be sufficient to map `/api/` to your backend app, and every request that starts with `/api/` will go to your backend app.

The key is that *everything* under `/api/` goes to the backend app. If you wanted to have `/api/v1`, `/api/v2`, `/api/v3` and `/api/v4` to go to backend and `/api/something_else` to go to another app then it would be more complicated because they all start with `/api/` and then you'd have to add individual routes in CF.

> Wildcards are not supported..at least I haven't been able to get them to work.

Correct. There is no specific wildcard character, but the match is basically a "starts with" match. If the path for a request starts with the path you add to your route, then it will match.

Ex: a route of `https://www.example.com/path1` matches `https://www.example.com/path1`, `https://www.example.com/path1/subpath` and even `https://www.example.com/path1/sub/sub/sub/sub/path` because they all start with `/path1`.

See "Create an HTTP Route with a Path" here for more details.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#create-route

Comment: Yes! This worked. I was missing the '/' at the end of /api. So it needed to be '/api/'. good catch sir!